# Access Denied al ejecutar una lambda en AWS

Tags: aws, lambda, amazon-s3

Estoy ejecuntando una función Lambda en AWS pero al parecer me aparece el siguiente error

```
   "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied",
"errorType": "ClientError",
```

Esta es la politica que estoy usando para poder acceder y con la decriptacion o KMS no hay problema por no se esta usando

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectRetention",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectAttributes",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAttributes",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Mi_Bucket/Pruebas/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::Mi_Bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de que puede ser?

Comment: Esa es la política que tienes en tu lambda, pero ¿Cuáles son tus S3 bucket policies?

Comment: Lo más normal es que esté sucediendo una de estas dos situaciones: No estás aplicando esta política a la lambda (revisa el rol asociado a la lambda) o hay otra política que esté devolviendo un DENY. O bueno, una tercera opción: el arn de la política no es el correcto